# One button click, with a high degree of success

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In the middle of implementing the app, I want to expose Admob ads on the 3rd click through the image save button.
I'm writing because I don't know how.
The function I want is to provide information about advertisements with a toast pop-up when the 1st and 2nd clicks are clicked.
Admob ads are displayed on 3rd click.

And when I click again, I want to know how to return to the first one, can anyone help me!
I'm a beginner, so I'm sorry for the lack of learning.

And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a counter variable and modulo (`%`), I would do like this:

```
private int clickCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    clickCount = 0;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.saveImage) {
        ++clickCount;
        switch(clickCount % 3) {
            case 0:
                showAdMob();
                break;
            default:
                showToast();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a structure that needs to be moved to the previous activity, but it is constantly initialized. Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: This is a structure that moves from mainactivity to fullscreenactvity, saves an image, and moves to mainactivity when back is pressed.